# How can I identify high value rows of data for each customer statistically?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, inference

I have a series of transactional data e.g. where each customer has bought. I need to separate the high value high frequency customers from the high value low frequency ones. How can i do this without having a definition.

My data is customer id, counts of transactions, sum of $ amount of these.

I am not sure how i can do this in mathematical way.

Comment: As I understand there is too little information in the question for a good answer. Apparently you will need some method of unsupervised learning. I would recommend starting with a scatter plot with counts or log(counts) on the x and amount (or log(amount)) on the y axis and then try cluster analysis on those. If everything else fails try a median split.